# angular2 how do you render a timer Component inside `ngFor`

Tags: angular, ionic2, zonejs

I want to render a visual countdown timer. I'm using this component, https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar, which relies on `SimpleChange` to deliver `changes.current.previousValue` & `changes.current.currentValue`.

Here is the template code

```
<ion-card  class="timer"
  *ngFor="let snapshot of timers | snapshot"
> 
  <ion-card-content>
    <round-progress 
      [current]="snapshot.remaining" 
      [max]="snapshot.duration"
      [rounded]="true"
      [responsive]="true"
      [duration]="800"
      >
    </round-progress>
</ion-card>
```

I'm using this code to trigger `angular2` change detection

```
  this._tickIntervalHandler = setInterval( ()=>{
      // run change detection
      return;
    }
    // interval = 1000ms
    , interval
  )
```

**updated**
(After much testing, I've discovered that the problem isn't the precision of the time I am rendering, and this question has been changed to reflect that.)

The problem is that `ngFor` is called multiple times inside 1 change detection loop. Regardless of my tick interval or the precision of `snapshot.remaining` (i.e. seconds or tenths of seconds) if `snapshot.remaining` happens to change on a subsequent call to `ngFor` during change detection, I get an exception:

`Expression has changed after it was checked`

If I render only a single timer without using `ngFor` then change detection works fine--even for intervals of `10ms`.

How can I render multiple timers on a page, presumably using `ngFor`, without triggering this exception?

**Solution**

After a bit of testing, it seems the problem is using a `SnapshotPipe` with `ngFor` to capture the snapshot of the Timer data. What finally worked is to take the `snapshot` of the Timer data in the View Component. As mentioned in the answer below, this uses a `pull` method to get changes, instead of a `push` method.

```
    // timers.ts
    export class TimerPage {
        // use with ngFor
        snapshots: Array<any> = [];

        constructor(timerSvc: TimerSvc){
            let self = this;
            timerSvc.setIntervalCallback = function(){
                self.snapshots = self.timers.map( (timer)=>timer.getSnapshot()  );
            }
        }

    }


    // timer.html
    <ion-card  class="timer"  *ngFor="let snapshot of snapshots"> 
    <ion-card-content>
        <round-progress 
        [current]="snapshot.remaining" 
        [max]="snapshot.duration"
        [rounded]="true"
        [responsive]="true"
        [duration]="800"
        >
        </round-progress>
    </ion-card>



    // TimerSvc can start the tickInterval
    export class TimerSvc {
        _tickIntervalCallback: ()=>void;
        _tickIntervalHandler: number;

        setIntervalCallback( cb: ()=>void) {
            this._tickIntervalCallback = cb;
        }

        startTicking(interval:number=100){
            this._tickIntervalHandler = setInterval( 
                this._tickIntervalCallback
                , interval
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first suspicious thing is `toJSON` (it has wrong name or returns `string` or converts string to array), which objects are contained in `timers` array?

During change detection for loop might be evaluated multiple times so it should not generate new objects. Also `toJSON` pipe should be marked as `pure` (see Pipe decorator options). Also it is better to provide `trackBy` function for `ngFor`. In general it is better in this case to update class field instead of using pipe.

---

```
public snapshots:any[] = [];

private timers:any[] = [];

setInterval(()=>{
    this.snapshots = this.updateSnapshots(this.timers);
}, 100);

<ion-card  class="timer"
  *ngFor="let snapshot of snapshots"
>
```

Comment: `toJSON` could easily be renamed `snapshot`, it returns a simple Object with `snapshot.remaining` in seconds with different levels of precision. I added a `trackByFn` but that did not solve the problem. `pure:true` does not help because `SimpleChange` needs the object reference to remain the **SAME** in order to capture `changes.current.previousValue` which equals `snapshot.remaining`. The problem is that the timer is ticking away in `MS` during the `ngFor` loop. As I type this, I'm thinking that a hack could be to debounce `snaphshot`...

Comment: I mean `throttle`, and I tried `throttle` at different values, but no luck. Also, it doesn't matter how fast the `ngFor` loop is, because as you mentioned, the change detection loop seems to call `ngFor` multiple times. if the timing value happens to change the error is thrown. This is true even if the precision is 1 second.

Comment: If I take the timer out of the `ngFor` I can render the timer every 10MS without an error. Updating the question to reflect this fact

Comment: I think in this case you should run `setInterval` in template owner compnent, and update snapshot array in callback, in other words push new values rather than let angular pull new values at random times.

Comment: That works!!! It's not as cleanly encapsulated, but it does seem to work. I can use `ngFor` and still render 100ths of a second with this approach. I'm going to wait a little bit to see if there is another approach this is better encapsulated with the Timer--but if not I will accept your answer.